# Delete 2 Cookies on click with JavaScript - How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, banner

I'm working on a Cookie Banner and I'm just wondering if its possible to delete two clicks on a button click?  Something like ...`onclick="eraseCookie(x, y)`"...

I'm new to JavaScript so I'm open to any ideas ;)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the names of the cookies, it's easy;

```
function erase(first, second) {
    document.cookie = `${first}=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;`;
    document.cookie = `${second}=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;`;
}
```